# Submarine diver game where you had to collect fish and other things for your aquarium

Tags: windows-98, windows-95, identify-this-game

I've been searching for a game that I used to play a ton when I was a kid on the Windows 95/98, but I can't find it for the life of me!

From what I remember, you were a deep-sea diver that collected fish to put into a fish tank. I vaguely remember solving math problems to get fish for your fish tank that was on your submarine (the math part may or may not be true because during this era I had a lot of "Jump Start" educational games and I may be getting this diver game confused with those)

I think the diver had a square helmet and big black eyes, and one feature of the game is that you could look out the periscope to see what was above the water. I can't remember any other specifics right now. Does anyone know the title of this game?

**Another's description of the game I am looking for:**

> This computer game was an ocean game where you look at fish underwater in a submarine I think. You were also able to have an aquarium where you can decorate the tank with statues and decorations you won. The front of the game disc had this diver with a scuba mask and flippers but it didn't look human. I cannot find it, I have checked mobygames, abandonware, wikipedia, etc. Some more information about my play of it was that it was also on windows, probably released between 1990 and 2002. The menu was a table with all your instruments within the submarine, you would play minigames or something to earn statues and decorations for your aquarium. (http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/9.166417-Old-Games-you-remember-playing-but-cant-remember-the-name-of?page=219)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Was it Math Ace Jr.? It was sold around 1994~1996.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's the one! Great find!

Comment: For some reason I have to wait a few minutes before I can award the bounty.

Comment: @RetroGamer In future I'd recommend allowing the bounty to _almost_ reach its end to maximise visibility of the answer so it gets more upvotes. Only five upvotes would double a +50 bounty.